# How to implement IF statement in Protractorjs Spec.js file?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to run `spec.js` file for multiple browsers i.e., using Multicapabilities in `conf.js`.

But I want one statement of code to be executed only for IE and I am trying to put that in IF statement by taking the title of the browser as the condition in IF. But the if statement is not getting executed and throwing me error as:

> object is not a function

Can someone help me how to write an IF statement in protractor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`browser.getCapabilities()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCapabilities):

```
browser.driver.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
    var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName;

    if (browserName === "internet explorer") {
        // ...
    }
});
```